# How do I "concatenate" text and a function in SQL Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following filter that I am trying to add to my query but I know it's incorrect at the moment:

```
WHERE plan_start_week=(date_part(w, CURRENT_DATE)-1)+1
```

Essentially, I want the above to say plan_start_week = "2020-06" (06 being the current week of the year). However, at the moment it will return plan_start_week = 6. I need to add the "2020-" so that it is in front of the 6 as the data in the column I am retrieving is of the format "YYYY-WW". The concatenate function concatenates text strings, but can I use this to do the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
select cast((date_part(y, CURRENT_DATE)) as int) || '-' || right('0' || cast((date_part(w, CURRENT_DATE)) as int),2)
```

Output is:

2020-06

Answer (score 0):

There is date masks defined for `to_char()` function : [Datetime Format Strings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html)

based on that use `to_char(current_date,'YYYY-WW')` to get your desired result.